# super argument correct or wrong

Tags: java

Can a constructor invoke the constructor of the direct superclass using the superclass constructor invocation? (i.e. `super(namelist);`)

Comment: Yes, that is kind of the purpose of the keyword.

Comment: Wouldn't actually testing this be faster than asking a question on SO?

Comment: A mouse over on the downvote button reveals : "This question does not show any research effort", kinda applicable here I'm afraid

Answer (score 2):

> Can a constructor invoke the constructor of the direct superclass using the superclass constructor invocation?

Yes it can.  But only as the first statement of the (subclass) constructor body.

```
public class A {
    public A(List<String> namelist) {
    }
    public A() {
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B(List<String> namelist) {
       super(namelist);
    }
    public B() {
       // implicitly calls 'super()'
       List<String> namelist = ...;
       super(namelist);  // Syntax error.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call constructor from subclass. i.e.

```
class A
{
 public A()
 {
   System.out.println("Class A");
 }
  public A(String str)
 {
   System.out.println("Class A"+str);
 }
}
class B extends A
{
 public B()
 {
   super("Hello World");
 }
}
```

Comment: Especially in this case, I think a coding style with opening braces without line break would save quite a lot of lines ;-)

Comment: Then it would have been even simpler for you to type it. I don't see why your IDE matters here oO Anyway, this was just an off-topic side note ;)